# Touchpad not working in Acer Predator Helios 300

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mouse, touchpad

My touchpad is not working in Ubuntu 18.04. I am using dual boot system and touchpad is working fine in windows. I have read several answers on how to fix this issue, but unfortunately none of them works. I have updated my kernel too.

When I change touchpad in BIOS settings to "basic" from "advanced", then touchpad in Windows is affected.

If you need any more information about my system please put them in comments.

Comment: This is mostly due than "advanced" mode is using i2c chip while "basic" use PS2 compatibility mode. Probably nothing to see with your Touchpad, probably the i2c chip in this Acer is not supported by Linux kernel.

Comment: Are you sure we can't do anything ? Because turning to basic from advanced has its side effects while using windows

Comment: What kind of side effect you encounter in Windows?

Comment: All of its gestures won't work without settings being in advanced mode. I have tried a few drivers too but that won't help.

Comment: This is a normal behavior, basic mode (PS2 compatibility mode) supports only few instruction like moving the cursor, using three button and a basic scrolling. Other gestures are working only with i2c chip.